# Do Linux cpufreq governers temporarily change sysfs's scaling_max_freq?

Tags: linux, cpu-frequency, sysfs

The linux documentation of the variable sysfs `scaling_max_freq` reports

> Maximum frequency the CPUs belonging to this policy are allowed to be
>   running at (in kHz).
>
> This attribute is read-write and writing a string representing an
>   integer to it will cause a new limit to be set (it must not be lower
>   than the value of the `scaling_min_freq` attribute).

My perception of the above was that I can use the following command

```
$ echo 2133000 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq
```

to indicate to the cpufreq governer that I desire cpu0 to be run at maximum 2133Mhz. After having set the value I can check it being set via

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq
```

which indeed yields 2133000

Now here comes the strange part, which prompts me to pose this question here:

During the executing of a cpu intensive task (e.g. a kernel build) I check the value in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq` and it reports 1199000, a much lower frequency.

Now I am puzzled: who did change the value? the cpufreq governer?

update/info to commends

- `dmesg` does not show any throttling messages
- `make -j4` was used so to use 4 four pipelines of the intel cpu (`model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz`)
- `uname -a` shows `Linux work 4.18.3-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 18 09:22:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux` hence my arch linux stock kernel
- cpufreq governer is `schedutil`
- `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver` shows `acpi-cpufreq`
- `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit` tells 2666000 which as I would expect the max freq of the cpu. (Should I check this value during cpu stress, or in idle??)

The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad X201t (tablet) model, whith the mains adapter being the original one supplied to the model at purchase. However I have temporarily switched the mains power supply adapter with another one and will report results.

To be absolutely clear. The value of `scaling_max_freq` is restored after the high cpu load task has ended. In "almost idle" state it again tells me the `2133000` originally set.

Comment: obvious question: did you remember to run your kernel build multi-threaded?  I.e. `make -j 4` (or maybe more) if your system has 4 logical cpus?  And, did you measure at a point where there were 4 processes?  IIRC the final linking step is single-threaded.

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks for enhancing the question with the pointers to required information (i was at a loss what to provide here). I edit the question with the information. With regards to the multi-threadedness I can say that the effect of suddenly having a lower value reported in `scaling_max_freq` was during the compile phase (not the linking phase). Anyway I would never expect the `scaling_max_freq` to be changed, if the freq changes I thought that to be exclusively in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_cur_freq`. But as it seems the value is temporarily changed.

Comment: [The `intel_pstate` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) suggests that `scaling_max_freq` is capped to the current P-state; your CPU is using `acpi-cpufreq` (Arrandale is too old for `intel_pstate`), so that doesn’t apply directly, but I imagine a similar mechanism could be involved here (if I’m reading the code correctly, the kernel updates `scaling_max_freq` on power-state changes). It’s not unusual for mobile CPUs to throttle down to much lower frequencies than their nominal frequency under load.

Comment: turns out laptop firmware is extremely weird, please report your laptop brand, model, age, and if your mains adaptor was new along with the laptop or is a replacement https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813156&p=11144999#post11144999

Comment: google says also check `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit`. If your issue was due to the bios detecting some issue with the mains adaptor, I would really expect `bios_limit` would show as the limiting factor.

Comment: can also be affected by whether the battery is still working: https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_CPU_frequency_scaling

Comment: @sourcejedi. Wow! this is really good. Your suggestion with the bios limit seems to get some result. I checked it logging the output in 1s intervals and at some point after the cpu load been high, also the `bios_limit` value is set to the reduced `1199000` value. This would explain why the other value in `scaling_max_frequency` is somehow adjusted to reflect the bios/hardware change.

Comment: cpufreqd perhaps installed and doing something in the background?